# Why does this simple YAML fail to parse or validate appropriately?

Tags: yaml, lint, pyyaml

This does not validate in several different YAML validators. It also fails to parse if read via PyYAML. Is this simply invalid YAML?

```
---
databases:
  - name: mydb
    migrations:
      - type: liquibase
        file: 1.xml
      - type: liquibase
        file: 2.xml
```

For example, YAMLlint produces the following error:

```
(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 6 column 13
```

Answer (score 1):

This is terribly annoying, and had nothing to do with the list of maps structure. Somehow there are whitespace characters in there that aren't ASCII, and neither PyYAML, nor the validators I tried, cope with those well.

```
$ xxd foobar.txt 
00000000: 2d2d 2d0a 6461 7461 6261 7365 733a 0a20  ---.databases:. 
00000010: 202d 206e 616d 653a 206d 7964 620a e280   - name: mydb...
00000020: 8220 e280 8220 6d69 6772 6174 696f 6e73  . ... migrations
00000030: 3a0a e280 8220 e280 8220 e280 8220 2d20  :.... ... ... - 
00000040: 7479 7065 3a20 6c69 7175 6962 6173 650a  type: liquibase.
00000050: 2020 2020 2020 2020 6669 6c65 3a20 312e          file: 1.
00000060: 786d 6c0a e280 8220 e280 8220 e280 8220  xml.... ... ... 
00000070: 2d20 7479 7065 3a20 6c69 7175 6962 6173  - type: liquibas
00000080: 650a 2020 2020 2020 2020 6669 6c65 3a20  e.        file: 
00000090: 322e 786d 6c0a                           2.xml.
```

See those `e28082`'s? They're En Space characters.